# Xcode 6 Interface Builder UITextView scroll issue

Tags: interface-builder, xcode6

OK, this is officially driving me nuts.  I have an "information" view in a tab of my app's main view controller.  The view has a simple UITextView with scrolling enabled.  If I set the view's constraints to a fixed size, center X and Y, for example, to look right on an iPhone 4S, it works fine, but when I run it on a larger iPhone, it will obviously have more space around the sides and top.  Still works, but it doesn't look optimal, especially on something big like an iPhone 6 plus.  So I use constraints to pin it to the edges of the super view, and it will then expand on the larger screens.  This should be the solution to my cosmetic problem, but unfortunately, when I set the constraints to do this, it always scrolls the view very slightly up so the first couple lines of text are offscreen.  I don't want my users to have to scroll down a little to start reading.  I've tried loads of different constraint strategies, but unless I give it a fixed size, it always starts out scrolled slightly up.  What am I missing here?

Xcode 6, iOS8, Size classes on and set to Compact width Any height.  I'm doing NOTHING in code with this view, it's all setup in IB.